# What are the steps for building a faceted search solution with RavenDB?

Tags: ravendb

I need to build a new search solution for our website that will allow users to quickly locate products that match their needs.  We want to use a faceted "Amazon.com" type of search and I want to implement using RavenDB.  Can anyone help me with defining at a high-level what the steps are to accomplish this from beginning to end.  I have already figured out a few of them and I have also determined that I am going to have to make use of [Dynamic Fields](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/advanced/dynamic-fields).  So here are the steps that I know of.  Any advice/direction/clarification would be greatly appreciated.

1. Download and install RavenDB
2. Setup the RavenDB Server (I have chosen to run under IIS)
3. Create object(s) to store data.  I know I am going to need to make use of Dynamic Fields since products can have different attributes.  My current objects look like this:

   ```
   public class ProductSeries
   {
       public Guid UID { get; set; }
       public String SeriesName { get; set; }
       public String SeriesDescription { get; set; }
       public String ProductIDInCMS { get; set; }
       public List<ProductAttribute> Attributes { get; set; }
   }

   public class ProductAttribute
   {
       public string Attribute { get; set; }
       public string Value { get; set; }
   }
   ```
4. Store documents in database.
5. Create indexes??? Here's where I get lost.  Is this the next step?
6. ...
7. ???

Ultimately, I know I will conclude with creating some sort of AJAX enabled control that will display facets with their values and counts and allow users to make selections that will filter our thousands of products down to a select few that meet their criteria.  I think I know where I start and where I finish; it's what happens in between that has me stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the docs about this?
They explain all of it: http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/faceted-search

Comment: Yes, I did.  But the docs for faceted search don't really cover using dynamic fields.  RavenDB (and NoSQL as a whole) is obviously new to me, so I am still trying to figure everything out.  I've also never used LINQ before.  So I have that learning curve to contend with.